# Number Theory Modulo

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I need to prove that if $k\cdot a \equiv k\cdot b  \ \ (mod \ n)$ then $a \equiv b\left( \mod \ \frac{n}{gcd(k,n)} \right)$

I tried to do this:
$$
k(a-b)=s\cdot n
\\
k=u\cdot \gcd(k,n)   \wedge n=v\cdot \gcd(k,n) \ ; \gcd(u,v)=1
\\
u\cdot \gcd(k,n) \cdot (a-b)=s\cdot v \cdot \gcd(k,n)
\\
u\cdot (a-b)=s\cdot v
$$
and now I'm stuck,
If anyone has some idea on how can I continue from this step or is there another way to start, I will be grateful!

Answer (score 1):

Now you have that $ua \equiv ub \pmod {v}.$ But $\gcd(u, v) = 1,$ and so $u^{-1}$ exists mod $v$. Multiply by it to get $a \equiv b \pmod{v}.$

Comment: How do I know $u^{-1}$ exists?

Comment: @JollyQ1 Because $\gcd(u, v) = 1$

Comment: yes but how do i prove it?

Comment: @JollyQ1 What number theory do you know? This is a standard but tricky lemma, usually proven with the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: *Please* strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242)